# Cron expression with start and end time

Tags: cron

I am trying to write an cron expression with a specific start time and end time everyday. i.e. 
every minute from 10:15 to 17:35 everyday

One possible solution for this is writing 3 different cron expressions like this:

```
0 15-59 10 * * *
0 * 11-17 * * *
0 0-35 17 * * *
```

Is there any possible way to write this in one single cron expression ?

Comment: Maybe run it from cron every minute from 10h till 17h and check the minutes only in your script?

Comment: @Marki555: that does not solve the problem at all, as I need to pass the cron expression to another server who will be using it to perform some jobs.

Comment: Note: there is one asterix too many on each line. (or better: the leading `0` should be omitted)

Comment: @wildplasser:

The format I have used is  - 
second minute hour dayOfMonth Month DayOfWeek
    0       15-59    10       *                  *             *

and excluded one more * for year, as it is not required.

Doc Reference : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html

Correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Quartz != cron. `man 5 crontab`

Comment: used reference is of cron expression only, but just from quartz scheduler's portal, that still doesn't change things. I believe.

And any normal single cron expression for the above problem!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no other way to achieve it using single crone expression but to specify multiple crone expressions for specific startDate and endDate.
There is a slight modification in second crone expression though (highlighted one)

0 15-59 10 * * *  (Every minute between 10:15 AM and 10:59 AM)

**0 * 11-16 * * *   (Every minute, between 11:00 AM and 04:59 PM)**

0 0-35 17 * * *   (Every minute between 05:00 PM and 05:35 PM)

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Scheduler c# 
run job between to hours

use corn mask:

```
        ITrigger trigger_1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .ForJob("YOUR_JOB")
            .WithIdentity("trigger_1")
            .StartAt(startTime)
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 8-13 ? *   SUN,MON,TUE,WED,SAT *")
            .Build();
```

use Quartz Schedule:

```
trigger_1 = TriggerBuilder
            .Create()
            .ForJob("YOUR_JOB")
            .WithIdentity("trigger_1")
            .StartAt(startTime)
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(c => c
                .OnEveryDay()
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(1).WithRepeatCount(1)
                .StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(08, 30))
                .EndingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(12, 30))
            )
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   HashMap<String, String> weekday = new HashMap<>();
    // String strDays ="[Monday, Friday]";
    String strCalDay = "";

    String startDate[] = fromDate.split("-");
    String endDate[] = toDate.split("-");

    weekday.put("MONDAY", "1");
    weekday.put("TUESDAY", "2");
    weekday.put("WEDNESDAY", "3");
    weekday.put("THURSDAY", "4");
    weekday.put("FRIDAY", "5");
    weekday.put("SATURDAY", "6");
    weekday.put("SUNDAY", "7");

    strDays = strDays.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    String strDay[] = strDays.trim().toUpperCase().split(",");
    if (strDay != null && strDay.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strDay.length; i++) {
            strCalDay = strCalDay + "," + weekday.get(strDay[i].trim().replace("\"", ""));
        }
        // System.out.println(" No of days :: "+ strCalDay);
        strCalDay = strCalDay.replaceFirst(",", "");
        //System.out.println(" No of days :: "+ strCalDay);
    }


    Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    startCal.set(Integer.parseInt(startDate[0].toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(startDate[1].toString()),
            Integer.parseInt((startDate[2].toString())));

    endCal.set(Integer.parseInt(endDate[0].toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(endDate[1].toString()),
            Integer.parseInt((endDate[2].toString())));

    int yearsInBetween = endCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthsDiff = endCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    long ageInMonths = yearsInBetween * 12 + monthsDiff;
    System.out.println("  ageInMonths: " + ageInMonths);


    if (startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) != endCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        if (ageInMonths == 3) {
            Calendar middleMonth1 = (Calendar) startCal.clone();
            middleMonth1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            Calendar middleMonth2 = (Calendar) startCal.clone();
            middleMonth2.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);

            int getFirstMMonth = middleMonth1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int getSecMMonth = middleMonth2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            if (getFirstMMonth == 0) {
                getFirstMMonth = 12;
                System.out.println("  getFirstMMonth : " + getFirstMMonth);
            }
            if (getSecMMonth == 0) {
                getSecMMonth = 12;
                // System.out.println("  getSecMMonth : " +getSecMMonth );
            }
            exp = strTimeMin + " " + strTime + " " + startDate[2] + "-" + "31,1-31,1-31,1-" + endDate[2] + " " +
                    startDate[1] + "," + getFirstMMonth + "," + getSecMMonth + "," + endDate[1] + " *";

            //  System.out.println("  expression for   month3 : " + exp);
        }
        if (ageInMonths == 2) {
            Calendar middleMonth1 = (Calendar) startCal.clone();
            middleMonth1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            //System.out.println("  get middleDate month : " + middleMonth1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            int getMiddleMonth = middleMonth1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            if (getMiddleMonth == 0) {
                getMiddleMonth = 12;
                //  System.out.println("  getMiddleMonth : " +getMiddleMonth );
            }
            //  System.out.println("  Outside getMiddleMonth : " +getMiddleMonth );


            endCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
            //System.out.println("  get middleDate month 001: " + endCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

            exp = strTimeMin + " " + strTime + " " + startDate[2] + "-" + "31,1-31,1-" +
                    endDate[2] + " " + startDate[1] + "," +
                    getMiddleMonth + "," + endDate[1] + " *";
            // System.out.println("  get end  month2 : " + exp);
        } else if (ageInMonths == 1) {

            exp = strTimeMin + " " + strTime + " " + startDate[2] + "-31,1-" +
                    endDate[2] + " " + startDate[1] + "," + endDate[1] + " *";
            //System.out.println("  expression for  one month : " + exp);
        }

    } else {

        exp = strTimeMin + " " + strTime + " " + startDate[2] + "-" + endDate[2] + " " + endDate[1] + " *";
    }

    System.out.println("  expression for  before parameter : " + exp);

    //Run with only Start Date
    if (strRepeat != null && strRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
        exp = strTimeMin + " " + strTime + " " + startDate[2] + " " + startDate[1] + " *";
    } else if (strRepeat != null && strRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Daily")) {
        exp = exp;
    } else if (strRepeat != null && strRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Weekdays")) {


        // System.out.println("  expression for  weekdays before  : " + exp);
        exp = exp.replace("*", strCalDay);
        // System.out.println("  expression for  weekdays after  : " + exp);


    } else if (strRepeat != null && strRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Weekends")) {

        // System.out.println("  expression for  weekend  before  : " + exp);
        exp = exp.replace("*", "6,7");
        // System.out.println("  expression for  weekend after  : " + exp);
    }
    System.out.println(" cron expression ::: " + exp);
```

Comment: Above code will execute cron expression for maximum 3 months start and end date as per the my project requirement.