# How to define CloudWatch events rate expression with start date and end date

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron

I have Node.js server that creates events in CloudWatch. To do that, I am using the object `CloudWatchEvents` under [`aws`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html) package.

I am actually creating trigger for lambda using CloudWatch, so the code below (that works) creates rule in CloudWatch that triggers lambda every two minutes:

```
const putRuleParams = {
  Name: triggerName,
  Description: description,
  ScheduleExpression: 'rate(2 minutes)'
}
const { RuleArn: ruleArn } = await eventsClient.putRule(putRuleParams).promise()
```

My question is how do I set the start date and the end date of the trigger using the `ScheduleExpression`? (I want to start the trigger next month)

What I already tried?

- I reviewed the examples under [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html). I didn't see relevant example with start/end date.
- I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832131/cron-expression-with-start-and-end-time) (but for time in same day) in SOF but not answered.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

The solution to question lies in below given two links.
1st you should understand [cron expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions) and then put an event as given in [NodejsEvent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putRule-property)

Comment: I reviewed these two links. I didn't see an option to create rule that will start next month (with rate of 2 minutes). Can you supply code example for this case?